# Php regex match a string between two html tags with the tags been unknown

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Ok, so here's my issue:

I have a link, say: http://www.blablabla.com/watch?v=1lyu1KKwC74&feature=list_other&playnext=1&list=AL94UKMTqg-9CfMhPFKXPXcvJ_j65v7UuV

And the link is between two tags say like this:

```
<br>http://www.blablabla.com/watch?v=1lyu1KKwC74&feature=list_other&playnext=1&list=AL94UKMTqg-9CfMhPFKXPXcvJ_j65v7UuV<br></p>
```

Using this regex with preg_replace:

```
'@(^|[^\/]|[^>])('.addcslashes($link,'.?+').')([^\w\/]|[^<]$)@i'
```

As such:

```
preg_replace('@(^|[^\/]|[^>])('.addcslashes($link,'.?+').')([^\w\/]|[^<]$)@i', "***",$strText);
```

The resulted string is :

```
<br***p>
```

Which is wrong!!

It should have been

```
 <br>***<br></p>
```

How can I get the desired result? I have blasted my head out trying to solve this one out.

I would like to mention that `str_replace` replaces even the link within another valid link, so it's not a good method, I need an exact match between two boundaries, even if the boundary is text or another HTML tag.

Comment: Please don't use Regex to match text between HTML tags. Use [DOMParser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Cthulhu Example Please!!! Also, note that the link is between two <br> tags because thats how tinyMCE formats text on new line

Comment: `http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/`. Look at the `How to get HTML elements` section.

Comment: I still haven`t found a solution. As I've seen, there isn't a solution where the br tags don't have an id or class attribute. Witing for a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to use a DOM parser for some reason, I believe doing what you intended is as simple as the following:

```
preg_replace('@(^|[^\/]|[^>])('.addcslashes($link,'.?+').')([^\w\/]|[^<]$)@i', "$1***$3",$strText);
```

This uses $1 and $3 to put back the delimiting text you matched in your regular expression.

As others have pointed out, using a DOM parser is more reliable.

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Excelent! Thanks a million :)